# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, facebook, mobile

Our react native release build gets many of these exceptions but we can't seem to figure out what's causing it. Any idea?
We are using hermes and fb button social login. Not sure if that helps.

These are the logs we get on Bugsnag:

```
This error is located at:
    in S
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in t
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in t
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in t
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in t
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTScrollView
```

...
in S
in b
in u
in h
in c
in RCTView
in Unknown
in RCTView
in Unknown
in C, js engine: hermes, stack:
S@1:1887428
wr@1:140917
Hl@1:179217
ja@1:164025
Ba@1:163883
Qa@1:163767
Ia@1:161335
anonymous@1:131495
anonymous@1:235311
ft@1:131080
ht@1:131313
pt@1:131207
ke@1:179615
_e@1:123929
Re@1:124218
receiveTouches@1:173809
value@1:96543
anonymous@1:95024
value@1:95988
value@1:94982

```
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java:-2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```